# cakephp join and mysql join

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, join

UPDATED!

i am relativly new in cakephp but having experience with mysql and php.
The model look like:

```
Person->Father
```

Father is self refered to person.

I wrote the following based on mysql query which gives back the father of "1" person
mysql:

```
SELECT `Father`.name,`Father`.id from persons as `Father` left join persons as `Person` on `Person`.`father_id`=`Father`.`id` where `Person`.id=1
```

cakephp

```
$options = array(
'fields' => array(
    //'Father.name',
    'Father.id',
),
'joins' => array(

    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Person.father_id = Father.id',
        ),
        'table' => 'persons',
//          'alias' => 'Person', i commented because having conflict with scaffolded model
            'type' => 'left',
        ),
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Person.id' => '1',
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Person','Father',
    ),
);
$data = $this->Person->find('first', $options);
$fatherquery=$this->Person->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Person.id'=>$data['Father']['id'])));
```

To get the same as mysql i have add this extra line(the last one $father=....,but now it seems subquery and look like the join isn't working) because of Father and Person are not the same model and if i have

```
$data['Father']['name'] and $data['Person']['name'] they are not equal
```

By the way i have a solution already,but maybe i misunderstand some concept.
Is there a way the get the mysql query easier?

Comment: What is $this->find('first', $options);? Do you mean $this->Person->find('first', $options); ? Where do you have this code? In which controller, model etc.

Comment: yes sorry it was not correct,you were right.
The code is in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  (Notice the lack of a contain.  The only reason to use contain is if you're not already getting the data in the main-model's find() or a join):

```
//Person model (cake 2.x code)
$this->find('first', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Father.id',
        'Father.name'
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Person.id' => 1
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'persons',
            'alias' => 'Father',
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Person.father_id = Father.id'
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: I made the join because i want to get the details of "Person1's" father
Sorry i made a small mistake:
$this->Person->find
Dave your find will return the details of Person1 and not his father

Comment: Updated answer.  I haven't tested, but the only potential issue I see is that you MIGHT need to include the 'Person.id' field in your fields array too in order to run the join successfully.  Thinking you don't, but if it errors, try that.

Comment: yes yo did it almost the same.
As i wrote above:

$data['Father']['name'] and $data['Person']['name'] they are not equal in mycase.I will have to work with Person and not Father.
I convert them by this:

$father=$object->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Person.id'=>$data['Father']['id'])));

But this is two step.Is there a way to get it in one step?

Comment: I believe I understood what you wanted, and believe my answer to be correct.

Comment: yes your answer is correct.
Lets say you save it to a variable $ask.
Now you can use
$ask['Father']['name'] or $ask['Father']['id']
But
I need to work on Person model.
$ask['Person']['name'] this will give me an error
no index 'name'

Therefore i need to "convert(its not a real conversion)"
$fatherquery=$this->Person->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Person.id'=>$ask['Father']['id'])));

Comment: @Andrewboy - why is that not mentioned anywhere in your actual question?  All you need to do is change the array key name?  Why not just set it?  `$data=$this->find...` then `$person['Person'] = $data['Father'];`

Comment: thank you for your comment,this was the answer for my question!